# How do I implement polymorphic dataclass models with default values in the base model in SQLAlchemy 2.0 / Declarative?

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I'm in the process of migrating to SQLAlchemy 2.0 and adopting new Declarative syntax with `MappedAsDataclass`. Previously, I've implemented [joined table inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance) for my models. The (simplified) code looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, MappedAsDataclass, mapped_column


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))
    foo_value: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(default=78)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "foo", "polymorphic_on": "type"}


class Bar(Foo):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("foo.id"), primary_key=True)
    bar_value: Mapped[float]

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "bar"}
```

The important bit for the question is the default value in `foo_value`. Because of its presence, a `TypeError: non-default argument 'bar_value' follows default argument` is raised. While moving fields around in the definition of a single class could make this error go away (but why is it raised in first place, since the field order is not really important?), it's not possible with inherited models.

How can I fix or work around this limitation? Am I missing something relevant from the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I needed to use `insert_default` with `MappedAsDataclass` instead of `default`, as [described in the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html#column-defaults).